# jFormattedTextField expand the text to cover the width

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I want to print a string in a `jFormattedTextField` in a swing `JFrame`. The string is different every time. It consist of one to twelve integers ranging form one to eighty plus a whitespace and a comma between each number. The width of the `jFormattedTextField` doesn't change. I want the string to fill the width of the `jFormattedTextField`. examples of the string is "1" or "2, 40" or "23, 40, 50, 60".

thanks in advance for any time or effort.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the textfield to shrink/grow according to its content? Or do you want the text within the textfield to spread across the available width of the textfield?

Comment: I want the text inside the textfield to spread across the available width of the textfield

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting its width programatically?

```
myFormattedTextField.setSize(new Dimension(newWidth, myFormattedTextField.getSize().getHeight()));
```

And compute `newWidth` according to the contents, as in:

```
newWidth = newString.length()
```

Comment: I don't want to change the size of myFormattedTextField. I want the sum of every character in the string equals the width of the myFormattedTextField

Comment: getSize().getHeight returns double the second argument for the constructor of the class dimession expects int

Comment: @IoannisPapaioannou you could simply use `getHeight()` directly, or cast the `double` to an `int` or use `getSize().height`. But anyway, this will not produce what you want. It will more or less size the field to its content. Btw, using `setSize()` is a very bad and poor idea